# How do I create an if () mouse is over an element in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, mouseover

I have some hover() JS code:

```
$( '.leftMenuProductWrapper').hover (
            function () {



            },
            function () {


    });
```

In the second function, I need something like:

```
If ($("#leftMenuWrapper2").hasMouseover){
do this
}else{
do that};
```

I can't find any documentation on how to do it.

**EDIT:**

This appears to be a solution:

```
$('#leftMenuWrapper2').mouseenter(function(){
    mouseover = true;
}).mouseleave(function(){
    mouseover = false;
});
```

And then later on in the code, reference it:

```
if(mouseover == false){
                doSomething
                };
```

Comment: Can you clarify; are you looking to perform a specific action when someone moves a mouse out of `$('.leftMenuProductWrapper')` and in to `$('#leftMenuWrapper2")`?

Comment: Also, can you include a bare-bones example of the DOM that this code is designed to work on?

Comment: @Jared, that's exactly the solution I was getting at in my answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At a very high level, what you want is something to:

- Hold a Boolean value.
- When the mouse triggers a MouseOver event, set the Boolean to true.
- When the mouse triggers a MouseOut event, set the Boolean to false.

All you have to do is return the Boolean value to get the `hasMouseOver` value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're doing but it looks like you're attacking this from the wrong angle.

I'm assuming you've got multiple elements inside `.leftMenuProductWrapper`, one of which is `#leftMenuWrapper2`... I assume the elements you care about are `<div>`s (but you can edit the code to fit if they're not). Try something like this:

```
$('.leftMenuProductWrapper>div').hover(function(ev) {
    if ($(this).id == 'leftMenuWrapper2') {
        // do something with this one
    } else {
        // otherwise, do something else
    }
});
```